# Typescript Error, how to do an if statement comparing object value and integer

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am attempting to learn typescript at the moment for use with Angular and in turn Ionic. I have a JSON string with the variable name 'barcodeData' which looks very similar to the following.

```
{ cancelled: 0, "text":"TEXT","format":"QR_CODE" }
```

To check whether a user has cancelled the barcode scanner, i need to run a check like:

```
if (barcodeData.cancelled == 0) {
    //user has not cancelled. Continue code.
}
```

Obviously the above would work fine in Javascript, but when trying to compile Typescript i get the following error in the console:

**Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and '0'.**

I have also tried single equals, triple equals and '== false' just in case it was coming through as boolean, however all of them yield the same error or it compiles and simply does not work.

Any ideas on how to top the error? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: How the variable is defined:

```
this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => { 
  if (barcodeData.cancelled == 0) {
    // continue execution
  }
});
```

Comment: How is `barcodeData` defined ? This works fine for example: ` var barcodeData= { cancelled: 0, "text":"TEXT","format":"QR_CODE" };
    if (barcodeData.cancelled == 0) {
        //user has not cancelled. Continue code.
    }`

Comment: Hi Titian, it is using a native plugin with ionic, the code looks somewhat like the following: `this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => { //if statement checks });`

Comment: Throwing this out there, if you're expecting a 1 or 0 on `cancelled` you can simply do `if (!barcodeData.cancelled) {...}`. No need for an equality operator.

Comment: Awesome stuff Z. Completely forgot the '!' check would work. Still it would be nice to know the reason why it isn't working.

Comment: It is not working because `barcodeScanner.cancelled` is somewhere declared to have type `boolean`. You still did not show us the declaration.

Comment: To see the definition in most IDE including visual studio code, put the caret inside `cancelled` and execute the action usually named "Goto Definition" (`F12` in vscode). Then, pls give us the resulting code and file name (probably a `.d.ts`).

Comment: Hi Henry, all i know is that at the top of the page I use `import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner'; ` and the docs tell me to use the code as listed above `constructor(private: barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner) { }` to which i then create my function: `QROpen() { this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => { // if statement }); } `

Comment: Hi Romain, getting 'No Definition Found' when running a definition check in Atom. Possibly because it is an externally loaded library. Also if the JSON is returning a value of '0' why is typescript assuming it to be boolean?

Comment: I think you could do !!0 in the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, after more research it looks like defining the type as any will prevent the error from showing. If anyone has a more accurate answer please enter below.

```
this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData:any) => {
    if (barcodeData.cancelled == 0) {
        // code works
    }
});
```

Letting **variable:any** in the then function allows the code to work properly.

EDIT: Also in this situation, running the (!) operator also allowed the code to work, but this may not in all future situations:

```
if (!barcodeData.cancelled) {
    // also works
}
```